# Drop Down Search Bar / View in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

If I have a navigation bar, then a small (header) view, and then a table view, is there a way that I can have a search bar (when a bar button item is pressed) drop down I between the navigation bar and the view below?

I have tried just shifting the view between the navigation bar and table view down, but it just goes over the table view instead of pushing the table view down, or else it would work great.

Any help is appreciated! Sorry if anything is confusing just let me know if I can clarify anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the search bar to "float" over the tableView on scroll, but when you scroll to the top of the list, then search bar doesn't overlap the tableView then you'll need to change the tableView's `contentInset`s to accommodate the search bar.

Something like:

```
tableView.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(x: 0.0, y: barView.bounds.size.height, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Then you'll need to scroll your tableView up to the top:

```
tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -barView.bounds.size.height)
```